# What is "linear" about the correlation coefficient used in multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution

The Pearson correlation coefficient is applicable only in cases where there is a linear dependence between two random variables. In multivariate normal distributions, we use the correlation coefficient $\rho$ with abandon as the non-diagonal element. What is essentially linear about $\rho$ that validates its usage? Is there an easy way to think about linearity with respect to this correlation coefficient?

Comment: Your meaning of "applicable" is strange, because it is equivalent to "nonzero." Could you please clarify what you mean by this word? This is a crucial point because the rest of the question is predicated on it.

Comment: @whuber: I guess I should not have used "applicable". I meant this usual formula captures only linear dependence, and I want to know what exactly is linear wrt multivariate Gaussians.

Comment: Let's use an analogy.  Length is a property of physical objects, just as $\rho$ is a property of bivariate distributions. Your question sounds like this: "Length is applicable only in cases where an object has a length. Carpenters use lengths with abandon to indicate the sizes of tables.  What is essentially "lengthy" about a table? Is there an easy way to think about length with respect to a table's length?"  Doesn't this sound a little strange to you?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions answer your question?  Notice that, in the bivariate case, E[X_1 | X_2 = x] is linear in x.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is linear about the multivariate normal distribution? It is that all conditional expextation functions of one component given all (or only some) of the others are linear functions. And, the slope coefficients in those linear function can be expressed as functions of the correlations (and variances) that describe that multivariate normal.  So, if you know that your data comes from a multivariate normal distribution, then you know that linear regression is an adequate model. The formulas can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions